# Merge content of textfile to every file in folder

Tags: python

I want to modify several text-files within a folder.
I have the following code:

```
if command == "deployf":
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(all_posts, topdown = False):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith(".html"):
                file_name = os.path.join(root, name)
                with open(file_name, 'r+') as fp:
                    lines = fp.readlines()
                    fp.seek(0)
                    fp.truncate()
                    fp.writelines(lines[:-9])
    print('deployed to all files')
```

This deletes the last 9 lines in every html file in a folder. Now I want to merge (or append) the content of another .html file to the end of every file in the folder but I don`t know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask for the path to the HTML file outside your loop:

```
path = input("Enter HTML File path to append to each file:")
```

Then read from the file:

```
root_content = open(path, 'r').readlines()
```

Then instead of removing the last 9 lines with `fp.writelines(lines[:-9])`, just write the `root_content` variable:

```
fp.writelines(root_content)
```

Im assuming this is what you want to do? You had all the knowledge shown in your problem to accomplish this, so please comment if i have misunderstood.

Comment: works. but i have to keep fp.writelines(lines[:-9]) to delete the last 9 lines and then write the content to the file at this position. If I don't keep it, the whole file is overwritten with the content.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need to replace the last 9 lines of each (`.html`) with the content of your other file, right ?

If so, and to reduce visible noise, I would use [`Path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) from [pathlib](/questions/tagged/pathlib) with [*slicing*](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) :

```
from pathlib import Path

if command == "deployf":
    all_posts = Path(all_posts)
    to_append = (all_posts / "the_other_file.html").read_text()
    
    for html in all_posts.rglob("*.html"):
        lines = html.read_text().splitlines()
        html.write_text("\n".join(lines[:-9] + [to_append]))
    
    print("deployed to all files")
```

If you need to replace a slice in the middle (*e.g 5:10*) of each (`.html`), use this :

```
        lines = html.read_text().splitlines()
        lines = lines[:4] + [to_append] + lines[10:]
        html.write_text("\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: an interessting way to do this. thanks.
Is there also a way to do this for example from line 5 - 10 and merge text in this area and keep the rest?

Comment: Easy to handle, see my update.